# Including wp-load.php causes fatal error inside a class method

Tags: php, wordpress

Im doing a direct .php call (ajax). Due to my classes, loading system, I would need to load wp-load later, not at the start.

So, if my file has only this:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
```

it runs ok. But if its wrapped inside a class:

```
class Paff
{
    public function x()
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php'; 
    }
}

(new Paff())->x();
```

it dies with a fatal error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::escape() in /var/www/wp-content/sunrise.php on line 11**

I cant see any reason why!

Comment: It makes no sense that you would include that inside your class to begin with. Place it outside of the class.

Comment: actually it does, for example I dont need it to include sometimes, to save up time

Comment: Just because you have a _reason_, doesn’t mean how you tried to do it actually _technically_ makes sense. Ask yourself one simple question: _Would I place all that stuff in there directly, if I had written it myself - does this functionality “belong” into my class here in the first place …?_

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to load a WordPress multisite outside of the normal parameters (judging by `sunrise.php` being the issue here). Try loading this file instead:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

This skips `index.php` which defines the `WP_USE_THEMES` constant and assumes you're not loading the front-end of the site (at least not traditionally, which you're not).

That should load everything and in the right order for you now.

Answer (score 1):

I also could not see anything wrong with your code. So I tested it with one change just for confirmation that it does work.

```
<?php

class Paff
{
    public function x()
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
        echo 'wp-load.php included. ABSPATH=' . ABSPATH;
    }
}

(new Paff())->x();

?>
```

It runs without error! and displays the following in the browser.

```
wp-load.php included. ABSPATH=D:\bronce/
```

I displayed the ABSPATH just to confirm that wp-load.php was included as it defines ABSPATH.

So this works as it should on my installation which is very standard as I just installed PHP a few weeks ago and I know I didn't change the defaults very much. So why does it not work on your system? It must be configured different. Is your system running any pre-execution handlers?

I just did a search for 'sunrise.php' which I originally thought was the name of your code. It may actually be an infection (or not) see https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/removing-backdoor-exploits/. I think given its name it is configured to run as a pre-execution handler. Some plugins legitimately install pre-execution handlers, e.g. WordFence. Unfortunately, I did not install WordFence this time and I don't recall the name of its pre-execution handler.

I just read the source code to WordFence. It does install a pre-execution handler but its name is ABSPATH . 'wordfence-waf.php'. However, WordFence also has a reference to '.../wp-content/sunrise.php' apparently executed before multisite loading. Are you using WordFence? Is your site a multisite?

**The important point is: The problem is not in your code but in a pre-execution handler. A pre-execution handler can be a huge amount of PHP code that can  significantly change the PHP execution environment, which is why plugins such as WordFence use it to monitor your code execution.**